# UPnP send/receive

Tags: java, nat, upnp

For approximately one week I have been trying to create a simple chat-program to learn how to use datagrams and sockets, proceeding with success I'm now trying to make a more functional final version of it, to test what I have learned but I have run into a huge problem.

Sending packets between two local computers is easy as a breeze, but when it comes to sending them to other computers on the internet port-forwarding have been an issue. Looking into this I discovered UPnP and created an automatic UPnP port on the client using Cling to make it more user-friendly, server-side I always port-forward "manually", which means it can always receive under normal circumstances. but the client is facing a problem I didn't anticipate: they can't receive datagrams through the UPnP port. if you port forward them "manually" they can receive (they can always send though, and the server reads them loud and clear).

So my question is: can someone show me how to send/receive (don't know if it's the servers fault or the clients fault, problem lies either in how the server receives, or how the client sends) through UPnP ports? or am I using UPnP ports all wrong? my router, which is the test subject, have UPnp port enabled, and I have tested UDP and TCP ports along with datagramsockets and multicastsockets in every configuration I could think of.

TL:DR use UPnP or find other solution on how to send/receive datagrams through a router/modem.

I am extremely sorry if the code is a bit messy/buggy, not the full code, will post pastebin if asked.

Client:

```
public class Client {

    public MulticastSocket rsocket = new MulticastSocket(25566);

    public Client() throws IOException {

    //creating UPnP port using Cling...
    InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    PortMapping desiredMapping = new PortMapping(25566,
            inet.getHostAddress(), PortMapping.Protocol.UDP,
            "Chatt program");

    UpnpServiceImpl upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl(
            new PortMappingListener(desiredMapping));

    upnpService.getControlPoint().search();

    // loop the loop to get values from text fields used
    // to receive messages from the server.
    //point of interest, this is where the client should receive data, works on a normal
    //portforward, doesn't on a UPnP port, no idea why.
    byte[] info = new byte[256];
    while (true) {
        DatagramPacket receive = new DatagramPacket(info, info.length);
        rsocket.receive(receive);
        String rmessage = new String(receive.getData(), 0,receive.getLength());
        System.Out.println(rmessage);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Client();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
public class Server {
    public MulticastSocket rsocket = new MulticastSocket(25565);

    public Server() throws IOException {
        String rmessage = new String("a message");
        // send to clients, not working on UPnP port
        send(rmessage, 25566);
    }

    public void send(String msg, int port) throws IOException {
        byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket gpacket = new DatagramPacket(message,message.length, address, 25566);
        rsocket.send(gpacket);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Server();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be having a problem with an upstream provider failing to pass your traffic?   Are you behind NAT?  Most tellingly, does anyone else's implementation of a similar idea work between the two computers in question.

Comment: There's some suggestions here http://mcis.jsu.edu/faculty/gfrancia/cs450/MULTICAST.pdf that you might find useful in tracking down your issue.  It could be your router has to be configured to route multicast packets externally (if it supports it at all), or it could be your providers firewalls/routers not supporting it.

Comment: multicast does not cross subnet boundaries, unless every router on the entire trip is specifically configured to propogate the traffic; that is never going to happen on the general internet. `nat` is going to break it anyway.

Comment: Wrong UPNP onfiguration - UDP can be forwardev via UPNP forwarded ports